# Get the live selected product variation stock quantity in WooCommerce

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

On my WooCommerce product page, I want to allow customers to pre-order (backorder) products when a variation stock quantity is 0 or less AND backorders are enabled for the variation.

To make this obvious to customers, the "Add to Bag" button text should change to "Add pre-order to bag" when a variation is selected that meets these criteria.

I consider a product as out of stock if stock level is less than 1. But in the product JSON, if backorders are allowed for a variation, then `variationData.[X].is_in_stock` always remains true whatever the stock value is. I would have ignored this and used the stock quantity but this is not in the product JSON.

I have achieved the functionality I want client side, but it is hacky (see below).

MY HACKY SOLUTION

Add a hidden html input field holding each variations stock quantity in `variation-add-to-cart-button.php`

```
<?php
    if ($product->is_type('variable')) {

        foreach ($product->get_visible_children() as $variation_id) {

            //gets the product variation based on its id
            $get_product_variation = wc_get_product($variation_id);

            //get each variations stock quantity
            $product_variation_stock = $get_product_variation->get_stock_quantity();

            //do whatever with variation stock
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="' . $variation_id . '_stock_qty" value="' . $product_variation_stock . '" />';

        }
    }
?>
```

I then use the following JS client side when the user changes the variation to get the selected variations stock level from the correct hidden field and use that in my logic to update the "Add to bag" button text.

```
jQuery('input[name=variation_id].variation_id').change(function () {
    const variationID = jQuery(this).val();
    const variationData = jQuery('form.variations_form').data("product_variations");
    const variationStockQty = jQuery('input[name=' + variationID + '_stock_qty]').val();

    //Find the current variation in the product JSON
    jQuery(variationData).each(function (index, variation) {
        if (variationID == variation.variation_id) {
            //Work out if the product is preorder or not
            if (variationStockQty > 0 && variation.is_in_stock && variation.is_purchasable) {
                jQuery('.single_add_to_cart_button').text('Add to bag');
            } else if (variation.backorders_allowed) {
                jQuery('.single_add_to_cart_button').text('Add pre-order to bag');
            } else {
                jQuery('.single_add_to_cart_button').text('Sold Out');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Any help towards a better way of achieving this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the selected variation stock quantity, you can use `max_qty` data argument:

```js
var stockQuantity = null; // Initializing variable

jQuery('form.cart').on('show_variation', function(event, data) {
    stockQuantity = data.max_qty;   
    console.log('stockQuantity: ' + stockQuantity); 
}).on('hide_variation', function(){
    stockQuantity = null; // Reset stock qty
});
```

Now, you can replace your code with the following:

```php
jQuery(function($) {
    var addToCart    = $('.single_add_to_cart_button'), 
        addToCarText = addToCart.text(); 

    $('form.cart').on('show_variation', function(event, data) {
        if ( data.max_qty > 0 && data.is_in_stock && data.is_purchasable) {
            addToCart.text('Add to bag');
        } else if (data.backorders_allowed) {
            addToCart.text('Add pre-order to bag');
        } else {
            addToCart.text('Sold Out');
        }
    }).on('hide_variation', function(){
        addToCart.text(addToCarText) // Add back the initial text
    });
});
```

Tested and works.

---

If you prefer to get the stock quantity (than the max available quantity) you can add it to the form data variations using:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'add_product_variation_stock_quantity', 10, 3);
function add_product_variation_stock_quantity( $variation_data, $product, $variation ) {
    $variation_data['stock_qty'] = $variation->get_stock_quantity();

    return $variation_data;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin).

Then in the JavaScript code you will replace `data.max_qty` with `data.stock_qty`.